# Turning a 3d swiftui view into an image

Tags: ios, swift, swiftui, uiimageview, uiimage

I've used the rotation3dEffect to rotate a UIImage. I am looking for a way to turn this new rotated version into a UIImage itself. I've tried using snapshot functions I've seen on here but it always formats incorrectly. Basically, would like to create a new image that has the rotation effect already applied.

```
Image(uiImage : image)
        .resizable()
        .aspectRatio(contentMode: .fit)
        .rotation3DEffect(
            .degrees(degX),
            axis: (x: 0.1, y: 0.0, z: 0.0)
            )
        .rotation3DEffect(
            .degrees(degY),
            axis: (x: 0.0, y: 0.1, z: 0.0)
            )
```

Comment: Please provide some code.

Comment: Please review [ask]... try to provide a better description of what you're trying to do. Do you want to generate an image of the *result* of the rotation effect? Do you want to get the "2d image" *used* for the rotation effect?